# removing the element via click in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying to remove an element using directive

i found a working example
http://jsfiddle.net/qDhT9

and i tried to append a new element and having the thing as
http://jsfiddle.net/qDhT9/140

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.directive('removeOnClick', function() {
        return {
            link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
                scope.remove = function() {
                    alert('here');
                    elt.html('');
                };
                elt.append('<a href class="close" style="float:right;padding-right:0.3em" ng-click="remove()">&times;</a>');
            }
        }
    });
```

but this

one does not worked.

Why and how to make the second one work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$compile` for any html you insert that includes angular directives:

```
app.directive('removeOnClick', function($compile) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
            scope.remove = function() {
                alert('here');
                elt.html('');
            };
            var link = $compile('<a href class="close" ng-click="remove()">LINK</a>')(scope)
            elt.append(link);
        }
    }
});
```

Also note that most of the time you can do this sort of removal by managing the model data and removing the data and let angular manage the dom. For example removing a row in an `ng-repeat` you would use a button to remove that item from the data array and angular would then remove it from the dom for you

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/20VxoyG9m4iG18sSdZdb)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a function to an element to trigger the remove function

try this,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('removeOnClick', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
            scope.remove = function() {
                alert('here');
                elt.html('');
            };
              elt.bind('click', function() {

                alert('here');
                elt.html('');
      });
            elt.append('<a href class="close" style="float:right;padding-right:0.3em" ng-click="remove()">&times;</a>');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think he wants the `elt.append()` to execute. You only had to call `ng-click` on the element to run `remove()`